# HtmlDocument ParseError not showing any errors

Tags: html-agility-pack, parse-error

I'm very new to HTMLAgility and playing with it. This is what I have so far

```
        HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
        var html="<html><body><img src=google-logo-874x28.png\"></html>";
        htmlDoc.LoadHtml(html);
        var errors = htmlDoc.ParseErrors;
```

Now when I try to debug the above code the variable "errors" is null (indicating there are no errors) when clearly there the  is missing and opening " is missing for src attribute.

What am I missing here? Why am I not capturing any errors.

Thanks,
Mateen